# Slide/scroll one long element by dragging a separate scrollbar/scrollbutton

Tags: jquery, slider, drag, owl-carousel, slick.js

I have a 900px by 300px image which is only visible in a 400x300 area, while the rest is hidden. I want to make a slider which either:

a) Keeps the image static while scrolling the visible mask area to reveal hidden parts of the image, or
b) Keeps the mask area static while scrolling the image to reveal hidden parts.

I searched hi and lo for any ready solution, but couldn't find one. The closest I got is the Slick jQuery library, which has an option to make one slider act as a navigation for another. Now the main problem is that I couldn't find a way to make Slick sliders slide continuously (the slider always 'locks' to the next slide, not allowing the slider to remain between the slides).

Also, I don't know how to make the slider scroll across one single large image continuously.

Are there any known tools to accomplish this?